# MapUtils with Logger

Tags: log4j, outputstream

I am using MapUtils.verbosePrint(System.out, "", map) to dump the contents of a map in Java.  They (management) do not like us using System.out.println().

We are using log4j.  They made the logger into a variable "l" so we can say something like l.debug("This is going to the logfile in debug mode).

I would like to get the output buffer(s) from l so I could pass it into verbosePrint() instead of System.out.  I looked at all the methods and members of the logger and did things like getAppenders() and tried all those elements but I could not find anything that helped.

Has anyone else done this?  I know the logger may write to > 1 output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Log4j IOStreams](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-iostreams/index.html) to create `PrintStream`s that will send everything to a logger. This is mostly useful to log debug output from legacy APIs like JDBC or Java Mail that do not have a proper logging system. I wouldn't advise it in other cases, since your messages might be merged or split into several log messages.

I would rather use one of these approaches:

- simply log the map using `Logger#debug(Object)`. This will lazily create an [`ObjectMessage`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ObjectMessage.html) (only if debug is enabled), which is usually formatted using the map's `toString()` method. Some layouts might format it differently (like the JSON Template Layout).
- eagerly create a `MapMessage` or `StringMapMessage`:

  ```java
  if (l.isDebugEnabled()) {
      l.debug(new MapMessage(map));
  }
  ```

  This gives you more formatting options. For example the layout pattern `%m{JSON}` will format your message as JSON.
- if your are set on the format provided by `MapUtils#verbosePrint`, you can extend `ObjectMessage` and overwrite its `getFormattedMessage()` and `formatTo()` methods.

  ```java
  public String getFormattedMessage() {
      final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      MapUtils.verbosePrint(new PrintStream(os), "", );
      return new String(os.toByteArray());
  }
  ```